# Keyboard takes Alphabets with Only one space between Words

Tags: regex, ios5

I've a text field which should take name and surname (in Alphabets) with only One Space between them.

I tried the following,

^[a-zA-Z]+$

it is working fine but takes only alphabets,

I want one space between the name like "Paddy Clark"

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$
```

Comment: Nop, it gives me NSInvalidArgumentException

Comment: Finally above Expression is working, I made mistake in my code so it gives me NSInvalidArgumentException.
Thanks M42.